# What does it mean when someone says, "I bid you no evil"?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when someone says, "I bid you no evil"?

Does this mean may good things come your way?

Comment: A line from Shakespeare?

Answer (score 3):

*Bid* is actually two different Old English verbs which have collapsed into the same form.  Here the sense intended is not “offer, present”, deriving from OE *béodan*, as when you *bid* at an auction,  but “ask *or* pray for”, deriving from OE *biddan*, as when you *bid* someone good day.

*You* here is the Indirect Object.

So *I bid you no evil* means  “I pray for no evil to you”—that is, “I hope nothing bad happens to you.”

Comment: Maybe the asker is unfamiliar with OE standing for Old English, I know that almost twelve months ago I would have been scratching my head if I saw that acronym :)

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I do have to point out that extending *I bid you no evil* to mean *I hope nothing bad happens to you* is going at least one step too far. *I do not hope that something bad happens to you* would be closer. It is an offer or a declaration of truce, or a grant of safe passage, or something in that vein; it doesn't quite rise to the level of well-wishing.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's pretty much the same as saying, in a slightly more formal way,  "[I bid you no harm](http://www.susanhaught.com/manuscriptspoetry.html)," i.e "I will not hurt you; I have no intentions to hurt you (now or anytime in the future)."

> "*Don't be alarmed. I bid you no harm. If your mother was alive, she would attest to the fact.*"

Answer (score -2):

It is a abominor based on the concept of  **Honi soit qui mal y pense**.  A term for for self-protection and in a sense it is similar to tossing salt over your shoulder to ward off bad luck:

**Honi soit qui mal y pense**:

> The motto of the Order of the Garter, the illustrious order of British
>   Knighthood, instituted at Windsor by Edward III., in 1348, as a
>   revival of the Round Table of King Arthur. The commonly accepted
>   translation—" Evil be to him who evil thinks "—is inac- curate; it is
>   more properly " Dishonour be to him who thinks evil of it."
>   -Origins and meanings of popular phrases & names, ... . Hargrave, Basil.